# Cannot containerize an ASP NET Core project with React inside Docker

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, docker, visual-studio

I'm new to Docker, I'm trying to create a test ASP NET Core project with React in Visual Studio 2022 and put it to Docker.

I follow [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022) to the letter.
I use Windows and have Docker Desktop installed and running.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this 
Dockerfile to build your images   for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the 
containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:nanoserver-1809 AS downloadnodejs
ENV NODE_VERSION=14.16.0
SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 
'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing 
"https://nodejs.org/dist/v$($env:NODE_VERSION)/node-v$($env:NODE_VERSION)-win-x64.zip"; 
Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; Rename-Item "C:\node- 
v$($env:NODE_VERSION)-win-x64" c:\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\\nodejs\\ C:\\Windows\\system32\\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\\nodejs\\ C:\\Windows\\system32\\
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["testdocker2/testdocker2.csproj", "testdocker2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "testdocker2/testdocker2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/testdocker2"
RUN dotnet build "testdocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "testdocker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testdocker2.dll"]
```

When I try to launch the project the build fails with the following error:

```
Docker command failed with exit code 1.
error CTC1014: The command 'pwsh -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 
'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip - 
 UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$($env:NODE_VERSION)/node- 
 v$($env:NODE_VERSION)-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; 
 Rename-Item "C:\node-v$($env:NODE_VERSION)-win-x64" c:\nodejs' returned a non-zero 
 code: 1
```

What can be the problem?

**EDIT**
I ended up using a Linux container instead of Windows (following the same tutorial), the test project is running fine now.

Comment: what is the command?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I just launch the app by hitting f5. Here's what the Output shows - docker build -f "path/to/Dockerfile" --force-rm -t testdocker2:dev --target downloadnodejs  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=testdocker2" "path/to/project"

Comment: Could it be that you are missing 2 back quotes in the big RUN command?

Comment: @Codo I copied the code from the tutorial , so if it's the case - the error is in the Microsoft site. Where exactly do you suppose 2 back quotes should be?

Comment: There are present on the Microsoft site (after `-win-x64.zip";` and `DestinationPath C:\;`) but not in your StackOverflow post.

Comment: @Codo Ah I see what you mean. Those quotes are there just because the code is written in a few lines instead of one. Look a bit further, at the complete Dockerfile, there the Powershell code is written in one line, no quotes there